# Proof of a basic proposition of improper integral using integration by parts

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I wonder how to prove the proposition below. Thanks!

> **Proposition**: If $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are real valued *continuously differentiable functions* satisfying $$\lim_{t \to \infty}f(t)g(t) = 0$$ then $$\int_a^\infty f(t)g'(t) \, dt = -f(a)g(a) - \int_a^\infty f'(t)g(t) \, dt.$$

Comment: have you got any ideas how to start?

Comment: The solution is in the title of your question.  Apply the definition of improper integral, then integrate by parts.

Comment: @Matthews Leingang: I think that the problem is if the two integrals $\int_a^{°\infty} f(x)g^{\prime}(x)dx$ and $\int_a^{°\infty} g(x)f^{\prime}(x)dx$ are convergent under the hypothesis that $f(x)g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $a=0$, $u(x)=\int_0^{x}(1+t)\cos(t)dt$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}\exp(-u(x))$, $g(x)=\exp(u(x))$. Then $f(x)g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$, so $f(x)g(x)\to 0$ if $x\to +\infty$, and $f(x)g^{\prime}(x)=\cos(x)$. Hence the integral $\int_0^{\infty}f(t)g^{\prime}(t)dt$ does not exists, and the formula is not correct. If you add the hypothesis that both the integrals $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)g^{\prime}(t)dt$ and $\int_a^{\infty}g(t)f^{\prime}(t)dt$ exists, the result is immediate, using the fact that $(fg)^{\prime}=fg^{\prime}+f^{\prime}g$.